# Android library implementation issue

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to follow along with the tutorial [here](https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-android-sdk#getting_started) for the android sdk. When I get to configuring the service listener, I am getting an error on build.

Code with error (inside MainActivity under OnCreate):

```
    aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
    aiService.setListener(this);
```

Error:

```
Error: method setListener in class AIService cannot be applied to given types;
required: AIListener
found: MainActivity
reason: actual argument MainActivity cannot be converted to AIListener by method invocation conversion
```

I've implemented to class here

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener {
```

AIListener class

```
public interface AIListener {
void onResult(AIResponse result); // here process response
void onError(AIError error); // here process error
void onAudioLevel(float level); // callback for sound level visualization
void onListeningStarted(); // indicate start listening here
void onListeningCanceled(); // indicate stop listening here
void onListeningFinished(); // indicate stop listening here
}
```

I know that the AIListener is being implemented by MainActivity correctly, however Android Studio is still telling me that the methods are not being used, even though I am overriding them in MainActivity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the implementation to ai.api.AIListener instead of implementing my own class, which is confusing, since that is what the tutorial tells me to do.... OH well! Perhaps it's out of date!

Answer (score 0):

Your activity will need to implement the interface AIListener, the current error indicates it does not as you are passing in a reference to the activity with the line

```
aiService.setListener(this);
```

Comment: I edited my question, but yeah I implemented it, that's why this is so confusing!

Comment: The AIListener is in a separate file, but yes all of this is under MainActivity.

Comment: I typed in the error wrong. It's fixed in the question.

Comment: Everything looks good then, could there maybe be two definitions of AIListener that are getting mixed up?

Comment: Yeah, something weird is going on. Android studio is telling me that none of my class' methods are being used, even though they are all overrided in my MainActivity file.

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: I tried that, but I have the same error. I would add that the AIListener class does say that it is implemented by the mainactivity, so I know that part is working at least.